# Running multiprocessing on two different functions in Python 2.7

Tags: python, list, elasticsearch, multiprocessing

I have 2 different functions that I want to use multiprocessing for: `makeFakeTransactions` and `elasticIndexing`. The function `makeFakeTransactions` returns a list of dictionaries, which is then added to the `async_results` list. So essentially, `async_results` is a list of lists. I want to use this list of lists as input for the `elasticIndexing` function, but I must wait for the first `p.apply_async` to finish first before I use the list of lists. How do I ensure that the first batch of multiprocessing is finished before I initiate the next one?

Also, when I run the program as is, it skips the second `p.apply_async` and just terminates. Do I have to declare a separate `multiprocessing.Pool` variable to do another multiprocessing operation?

```
store_num = 1
process_number = 6
num_transactions = 10

p = multiprocessing.Pool(process_number)
async_results = [p.apply_async(makeFakeTransactions, args = (store_num, num_transactions,)) for store_num in xrange(1, 10, 5)]

results = [ar.get() for ar in async_results]
async_results = [p.apply_async(elasticIndexing, args = (result_list,)) for result_list in results]
```

EDIT:

I tried using `p.join()` after `async_results`, but it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\workspace\Proj\test.py", line 210, in <module>
p.join()
File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 460, in join
assert self._state in (CLOSE, TERMINATE)

AssertionError
```

Comment: Call ``.join()`` on the pool?

Comment: @JamesMills so use `p.join()`? I tried using that, but it gave me an `AssertionError`

Comment: Add the traceback please to your question and the fact you've tried this.

Comment: @JamesMills Sorry, I meant to say I tried it after you suggested it. Thanks for the tip! I've added the traceback

Comment: If you want the first task to finish before starting the second one, *why are you using apply_async*? Use `map` or `apply` instead.

Comment: @RolandSmith makes a very good point; you *should* probably use ``map()`` or ``.apply()`` here so the pool is kept open and your two batches are run sequentially.

Comment: @RolandSmith @JamesMills Okay, you're right, I changed it to `p.apply()` instead and I have the error `MemoryError: out of memory`. Could I just call `p.apply()` for my second batch instead of setting it to be `results = [p.apply(etc.)]`

My second function doesn't return anything either.

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I just realized I should be using the 64 bit version of Python since I'm working with large amounts of data :) Thanks!